# Updating a single object when its geometry changes

Tags: three.js

I would like to have a specific object updated because its vertices have changed.

The doc is saying to set `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate` to `true`. However, this is working only if `autoUpdateObjects = true` in the renderer.

If not, it seems the only thing you can do is calling by hand `initWebGLObjects` so that your objects are updated.

However, `initWebGLObjects` is looping over all objects in the scene, which seems overkilled knowing that I have a single (or a couple) of objects to update each frame.

Is there a way to flag my objects as needing an update without having to call `initWebGLObjects` ?

Comment: This is a pretty sophisticated question. I'd suggest that you turn this into an enhancement request and repost it on the three.js board, with a compelling example if possible.

Comment: I have opened a request on github about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question closed, I have opened a request on GitHub instead.